Dependency Conflict: Unable to Install @ngx-formly/ionic with @ionic/angular 8.3.1
I'm working on an Angular project where I'm trying to integrate @ngx-formly/ionic for creating dynamic forms and form handling. However, I'm facing a dependency conflict during installation. Currently, I have the following version of Ionic installed: - @ionic/angular: 8.3.1
When I attempt to install @ngx-formly/ionic, I get the following error message:
npm install @ngx-formly/ionic
npm error code ERESOLVE
npm error ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency tree
npm error
npm error While resolving: apartment-auditing@0.0.1
npm error Found: @ionic/angular@8.3.1
npm error node_modules/@ionic/angular
npm error   @ionic/angular@"^8.3.1" from the root project
npm error
npm error Could not resolve dependency:
npm error peer @ionic/angular@"^6.0.0 || ^7.0.0" from @ngx-formly/ionic@6.3.7
npm error node_modules/@ngx-formly/ionic
npm error   @ngx-formly/ionic@"*" from the root project
npm error
npm error Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm error this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm error to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.

                                                                

I do not want to downgrade my @ionic/angular version as I need the latest features and fixes. Is there a compatible version of @ngx-formly/ionic that works with @ionic/angular 8.3.1? If not, what are my options to resolve this conflict without downgrading?
Any guidance or solutions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

as you can see in the error logs the the library is not updated with latest ionic and looks for 6.0.0 || ^7.0.0. you can use npm i @ngx-formly/ionic -f o forcefully install it.
